# How to make an Uptime command for a Discord administrator bot in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

So... To give you a bit of context, I need to tell you what I have done. I have created a discord bot for moderation (mellobot.net) and I need help with a command. I would like to put an -uptime command for the actual bot itself to display the time in DD HH MM, but have no idea what the command line would look like. (I want something like NightBots !uptime that twitch users use for twitch streams) Are there any discord.py nerds that would help me with this predicament?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but maybe you can use `datetime` module. When the bot is `on_ready`, you can take the date, and make a `!uptime` command like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global startdate
    startdate = datetime.now()
@client.command()
async def uptime(ctx):
    now = datetime.now()
    uptime = startdate - now
    uptime = uptime.strftime('%d/%h/%M')# I don't remember the date's well, might be the lowercases are false.
    await ctx.send(f'Uptime: {uptime}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the time your program started, then, do some math. The `on_ready()` event can and will fire multiple times during the uptime of a bot and bad things usually happen if you do anything more than print a message inside it.

```py
from datetime import datetime

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')
bot.launch_time = datetime.utcnow()

@bot.command()
async def uptime(ctx):
    delta_uptime = datetime.utcnow() - bot.launch_time
    hours, remainder = divmod(int(delta_uptime.total_seconds()), 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
    await ctx.send(f"{days}d, {hours}h, {minutes}m")
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the latest workign command for discord.py re-write**

````py
@commands.command()
    async def uptime(self, ctx):
        delta_uptime = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self.bot.launch_time
        hours, remainder = divmod(int(delta_uptime.total_seconds()), 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
        days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
        e = discord.Embed(title=f"I've been up  for {days}d, {hours}h, {minutes}m, {seconds}s,", color=discord.Color.green())
        await ctx.send(embed=e)```
````